# Silverlight three state checkbox implementation via two states

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I need to handle three state checkbox in the following manner based on the first value:

- If checkbox in a checked state then It can be only unchecked.
- If checkbox in a uncheck state then it can be only checked.
- if checkbox in a middle state then it can be only checked.

Can you please suggest on how this can be implemented?

Comment: Hi, I have resolved it, Using Unchecked, checked and indeterminate events

Comment: You should post your resolution as an answer to benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be resolved via in-built checkbox implementation. That is, using Unchecked, checked and indeterminate events. [More info on microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ms609112(v%3Dvs.95))

Answer (score 0):

to resolve your problème you chould handle tree event and set the attached property

**IsThreeState** to true,look at the example:

```
<checkbox IsThreeState="True"
Indeterminate="checkbox_Indeterminate"
Unchecked="checkbox_Unchecked" Checked="checkbox_Checked"
Content="Click me!"/>
```